# I want to drag an image to my pdf file using itext java

Tags: java, image, size, itext

I have a requirement to perform drag and drop functionality
using iText jar file.
and also I want to set the image width and height any help grately appriciated.

I am using the following code but unable to set the size of the image(Hint: Half of my PDF page will contain  Image but I am unable to do that)

below is my code:

```
        String imgLoc = "E:/iText/Image1.jpg";
        Image image = Image.getInstance(imgLoc);
        image.setAbsolutePosition(100, 140);

        image.scaleToFit(100f, 70f);
        // image.setAbsolutePosition(280, 10);
        // image.setAbsolutePosition(absoluteX, absoluteY);
        // writer.getDirectContent().addImage(image);

        document.add(preface1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with .scalePercent() method. For example, if you want to reduce the size at 50% you can do:

```
    image.setAbsolutePosition(100, 140);
    image.scalePercent(50f);
```

Try different values until you get the one that fits you.

Answer (score 0):

This question is more or less unanswerable because you want the image to cover "half of the page", but you don't tell us how you defined the page size.

If you created your `Document` like this:

```
Document document = new Document();
```

Then you implicitly defined the page size: the default page size is A4. In other words: what you're doing is equivalent to this:

```
Rectangle pagesize = new Rectangle(595, 842);
Document document = Document(pagesize);
```

Hence, if you want an image to cover half of the page, you need something like this:

```
image.scaleToFit(pagesize.getWidth(), pagesize.getHeight() / 2);
```

Note that the `scaleToFit()` method respects the *aspect ratio* of the image, so it is possible that the image is smaller than half the page size. If you really want to use the exact half of the page, you need:

```
image.scaleAbsolute(pagesize.getWidth(), pagesize.getHeight() / 2);
```

However: this may result in an ugly result with an image that looks unnatural because it's stretched to fit absolute dimension.

Depending on whether you want to add the image to the upper half of the page or the lower half, you need:

- Lower half: `image.setAbsolutePosition(0, 0);`
- Upper half: `image.setAbsolutePosition(0, pagesize.getHeight() / 2);`

In your code, you are using hard-coded dimensions and positions. It would be very surprising if those values correspond with half of the page.

Comment: Thank you lowagie its working very fine!.Please let me know can't we drog and drop! or upload a image manually.And I am defining the page size as follow Please suggest me whether I am following right syntax or not If not Please let me know what is the better way to define a page or document format. Here is my Doc format

Comment: Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4,40.0f,40.0f,5.0f,5.0f);

Comment: How on earth would you use iText (a library without any GUI whatsoever) to drag on drop an image manually? Your question sounds like: I'm looking at my radio. How can I see my favorite TV-show? Radio doesn't show movies. iText isn't a tool that can be used "manually". It's a developer library. As for your `Document` object: that looks fine.